# Clash of clans not compatible with honor 4c

Tags: clash-of-clans

I m not able to install clash of clans on my new honor 4c please help me to install it.I search the name of COC but I don't get any.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try following the Play Store link:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.supercell.clashofclans&hl=en

Comment: Can you also tell me link for clash royal.